# C floating point variable not storing decimal

Tags: c, input, floating-point

I'm creating a kind of cash register program for a class, it takes a purchase amount and an amount tendered and gives the remaining amount and dividing it up into how many of each bills to give. The problem is that when I try to store a float it doesn't store the numbers to the right of the point.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    float purchase_amount = 0.00f,
        amount_tendered = 0.00f,
        calculated_return = 0.00f;
    float *p_return_amount;

    printf("Welcome to Change Counter!\n\n");

    printf("Please enter the total amount of purchase: ");
    scanf("%f", &purchase_amount);

    printf("\nPlease enter amount of money tendered: ");
    scanf("%f", &amount_tendered);

    // Debug output
    printf("\n\nPurchase Amount: %.2f\nAmount Tendered: %.2f ", purchase_amount, amount_tendered);

    calculated_return = amount_tendered - purchase_amount;
    p_return_amount = &calculated_return;

    printf("\n\nYour change is: %.2f", *p_return_amount);

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESSFUL;
}
```

It only happens with really large numbers which is exclusively what I'm working with. Say 14990300.54 and say 15000000.21 just stores 14990301.00 and 15000000.00. I automatically rounds up for some reason.

Is there a problem with my syntax? Is floating point too small?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size and precision of the type `float` can vary from one system to another, but it's typically 32 bits and only about 7 decimal digits, which is consistent with what you're seeing.

Changing to type `double` (typically 64 bits and about 11 decimal digits) may be good enough for what you're doing.

But keep in mind that floating-point actually stores values in *binary*, not decimal. For example, the value `0.01` cannot be stored exactly as a binary fraction, any more than `1.0/3.0` can be stored exactly in decimal.

In real life, you probably don't want to use floating-point for calculations involving money. A good alternative is to store all amounts as integers representing the number of cents (or whatever the smallest amount is that you need to deal with), and scale as needed on input and output. For example, a 32-bit signed integer type can store amounts up to about 21 million dollars; a 64-bit signed integer can store more money than you'll need to worry about (as long as you're not dealing with [Zimbabwean dollars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwe_dollar)).

A simple example: say you have a `long int` value representing $123.45 as `12345`. You could print it as:

```
printf("%ld.%02d\n", value/100, value%100);
```

This isn't *always* good enough. For example, if you're doing interest calculations, adding 10% interest to `123.45` gives you `135.795`, which is not a whole number of cents. I understand that there are laws that specify exactly how banks and other financial institutions must perform such calculations. I personally have very little idea what those laws actually say -- and for what you're doing now, you probably don't need to either.

On the other hand, it may be that floating-point is good enough for your current purposes, even though you can gain or lose a spurious penny here and there due to roundoff error. Ask your instructor, and keep in mind that it's *not* good enough for real-world monetary calculations, at least not without extraordinary care.

I suggesting adding Goldberg's ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to your list of Things To Read Some Day. It's probably too detailed for what you're doing now, but it's worth keeping in the back of your mind.

Comment: So how would one split up a double into dollars and cents integers?

Comment: @user1892641 You don't split anything. You have an invisible fixed decimal place. Instead of decimal 189.27, you store int 18927 or instead of decimal 328.6, you store int 32860. Only when you read or write numbers, you must allow for the decimal point.

Comment: @user1892641: And you don't store it in a `double` in the first place. Just reading `"1234.56"` into a `double` risks storing it as, say, `1234.55999999999994543031789362430572509765625`, which could accidentally be truncated to `1234.55`. Financial institutions operate under even more stringent rules; I'll update my answer to discuss that.

Comment: *Decimal floating-point* was standardized precisely to manipulate monetary amounts, even if they are in Zimbabwean dollars. Everyone understands “floating-point” to mean “binary floating-point” by default, but since the topic is the representation of currency amounts, the distinction is worth making.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Good point -- but it's likely that the OP's system doesn't support decimal floating-point.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to have all that when a simple double stores what I need to the precision I need. Even if it goes out too many places I have a global called PENNY_AUTO_ROUND = 0.005 I add to the end of my penny calculation (since it forces to round down).

Comment: @user1892641: Yes, you can do that (that's covered by "extraordinary care" at the end of my answer). `double`, if it's 64-bit IEEE (as it commonly is), can represent amounts well into the trillions of dollars with sufficient precision. But you have to handle roundoff correctly for *every* calculation you perform; if you miss it in one place, you can easily truncate 12.339999999... to 12.33, losing a penny. As I said, it's probably good enough for an introductory class (you're studying programming, not high-stakes finance).

Comment: @user1892641: And see the reference I just added to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`float` stores only 7 significant digits. If you want more precision, use `double` instead. `double` can store 16 significant digits.

See also [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for more details about floating point numbers.

Comment: The size and precision of `float` can vary from one system to another. 32-bit IEEE representation is certainly the most common, and probably what the OP is using, but it's not universal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, floating point values are imprecise by design, and a `float` will give around 6 decimal places.

Never use floating point values for currency. Use integers, with appropriate rounding rules. (i.e. count in whole pennies/cents, and ensure that when dividing up quantities, the sum is preserved.)

Comment: Thanks, what should I use?

Comment: Use integers for currency?  Really?  I hope my bank doesn't take your advice.

Comment: @EdS. Yes, really. I'm not sure what the complaint is with this suggestion, but if I were dealing with money, I'd use something guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: @EdS. There's nothing wrong with using integers and a fixed decimal place.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Well perhaps I misunderstood what Jason meant when he said: *"Use integers, with appropriate rounding rules"*